# How can I create a folder named like the current date in bash

Tags: terminal, macbook-pro, bash

So I'm messing around in my .bashrc making different aliases and playing with my prompt. I'm trying now to make an alias that will move into a specific directory, make a new directory based on the date, and make a new file. All in one alias. Here's what I've done...

```
export DATE="$( date +%d-%b )"
alias hw='cd ~/Java/Homework/257; mkdir $DATE; cd $DATE; vim'
```

Now if I go out and run `hw Client.java` it should move into `~/Java/Homework/257/27-Jan/` and open a new file called Client.java in vim. It all works beautifully except the date variable doesn't work right. It moves me into the ~/Java/Homework/257 directory and makes two directories. One called date and another called +%d-%b and puts the Client.java file in the date directory.

I thought my date variable export simply wasn't working but when I type $DATE at the command prompt it gives me 27-Jan like it should. So does anyone know what could actually be causing this? A friend of mine did something very simliar to this using a slightly different format string for the date and his works just fine. The only thing I have different on my computer is bash-completion from homebrew but I don't see how that would effect my date...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export DATE="$( date +%d-%b )"
```

You need to actually execute it. Otherwise you just assign a string value. Since you're missing quotes around the `$DATE`, it will be interpreted as two separate arguments, `date` and `+%d-%b`.

Comment: This "works" in a way. It fixed the date issue, my problem now is that it isn't doing everything else in the alias first. It's supposed to change directories into my homework directory before it makes the date directory and opens vim.

Comment: Nevermind I figured out the problem! I messed up the path to the homework directory.

Comment: @CaldwellYSR Glad my answer helped.

Comment: @CaldwellYSR: If you use say `cd wherever && mkdir "$DATE" && cd "$DATE" && vim` (i.e. use `&&` instead of `;`), it will be easier to notice when one of those middle commands fails (the rest will not run and the failing one (the last one run) will probably have written an error message).

Answer (score 2):

Try to define go as a function in `.bashrc` or `.alias`:

```
go() {
    DATE=$(date +%d-%b)
    mkdir "$DATE"
    cd "$DATE"
    vim "$1"
}
```

This ensures that the date is determined every time you use the command and not just when you login/start bash.

Comment: That had the unfortunate side effect of infinite loopage somehow and now I have 17million directories deep of 27-jan XD

Comment: How did you call the function?

Comment: go()... is that not how to call it?

Comment: Just typing `go` is enough

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of the other answers: you need to execute the date command.  Probably the simplest solution would be to change your quotes to back ticks:

```
export DATE=`date +%d-%b`
```

Comment: OH They are back ticks... I thought it was single quotes. That's what I was messing up!!!

Comment: In the alias statements you need quotes, as you are just replacing, for example, `go` with that literal string.  When you want to execute code, you can place it in back ticks or use the `$(...)` formalism mentioned in the other answers.